# Custom style for part of a Chakra-ui component

Tags: chakra-ui

I have a Chakra-ui radio button for which I would like to apply a custom style when it is disabled. in particular a disabled Chakra radio uses `opacity: 0.4` on its label, whereas I want to set that to 1.

I have created a variant called `readonly`, but the styling in that variant is not being applied to the radio label.

```
      <Radio
        isDisabled={isRadioDisabled}
        value={Number(option.value)}
        variant={"readonly"}
      >
        {option.label}
      </Radio>
```

The custom style containing the variant:

```
{
  baseStyle: {},
  variants: {
    readonly: {
       opacity: 1
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the Chakra radio in the dev tools you'll see some class attributes that include a double underscore.

[image: radio_in_dev_tools]

These are the `parts`. We can see that the radio is actually a multi-part component. The label you want to work with is actually a `<span>`, which is highlighted in the image. It has a class that ends with `__label`.

Also, you only want to change the opacity when the label is disabled. Using an underscore will allow you to access the disabled state.

Your variant's custom style looks like the following, with a `part` of 'label' noted:

```
{
  baseStyle: {},
  variants: {
    readonly: {
      parts: ["label"],
      label: {
        _disabled: {
          opacity: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Can I use custom style in place? Like directly in ```<Radio>```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But I couldn't find anything related to this in official docs. Can you share the link regarding this part if you know  in official documentation?

Comment: Sorry @rufatZZ this is all a fading memory now, but I don't think I was able to get too much out of the docs. It was more about going into the repo as well as looking at  tickets.

Comment: Thanks again! I needed something regarding Icons inside `<Button/>` but turns out it is counted as multi-part component